# Get Value of array with multiple values

Tags: php, laravel

i know that has to be a trivial one. Can please somebody tell me how only to get the value of skills? how can i access it?

[image: array]

Appreciate.

Comment: Show us some codes that you tried to get the value from JSON

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1427878)

Comment: If you want to get them all in one go: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: `foreach ($like_values as $key => $like_value)
                  {
                     $out = null;
                     $out = DB::Table('employees')->where('skills', 'like', '%'. $like_value .'%')->get();

                      if ($out == null)
                        {}
                      else {
                          foreach ($out as $out_value) {
                              array_push($results, $out_value);
                          }
                      }


                  }

     dd( $results); `

Comment: Sorry guys i messed this Q up. i cant edit my question. I should have added code of course. Thought its just a simple one.  It's just an array i am not usting json or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different options to choose from:

1. In plain PHP you can do:

```php
$skills = array_map(function($entry) {
    return $entry->skills;
}, $arr);
```

2. With Laravel helpers you can do:

```php
Arr::pluck($arr, 'skills');
```

3. Your data looks like models so in that case, you might be able to do this as well:

```php
YourModel::get()->pluck('skills'); //or
$yourCollection->pluck('skills');
```

Comment: Laravel Helpers worked for me. Thanks a lot.